# How do i change this laser rangefinder python code to detect a green dot instead of a red dot?

Tags: python

So my friends and I were tying to assemble this homemade laser range finder that someone posted on this website: http://shaneormonde.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/webcam-laser-rangefinder/. It was all going fine until we hit the python code section, as we were not familiar with any programming language. As the project on the website describes, it is supposed to detect a red dot in the field of view of a webcam. Unfortunately, we already bought a green laser. How do you change the code so that it detects a green dot instead? Here is the code:

```
## program written by Shane Ormonde 7th sept 2013
## updated on 25th January 2014
## calculates the distance of a red dot in the field of view of the webcam.


import cv2
from numpy import *
import math

#variables
loop = 1

dot_dist = 0

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(1)



if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()

else:
    rval = False
    #print "failed to open webcam"


if rval == 1 :

    while loop == 1:
            cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
            rval, frame = vc.read()
            key = cv2.waitKey(20)
            if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                loop = 0
            num = (frame[...,...,2] > 236)
            xy_val =  num.nonzero()

            y_val = median(xy_val[0])
            x_val = median(xy_val[1])

            dist = ((x_val - 320)**2 + (y_val - 240)**2 )**0.5 # distance of dot from center pixel
            dist = abs(x_val - 320) # distance of dot from center x_axis only

            print " dist from center pixel is " + str(dist) 

            # work out distance using D = h/tan(theta)

            theta =0.0011450*dist + 0.0154         
            tan_theta = math.tan(theta)



            if tan_theta > 0: # bit of error checking
                obj_dist =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)


            print "\033[12;0H" + "the dot is " + str(obj_dist) + "cm  away"
elif rval == 0:
        print " webcam error "
```

Comment: My guess is that `vc.read()` reads in an BGR image, stored in `frame`. So `frame[...,...,2]` is the red channel and `frame[...,...,1]` should be the green. Check the documentation to verify that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have time to try it right now so i'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

`rval, frame = vc.read()` reads in an image in BGR format. The tutorial page you linked outright states so.

> So all of the pixel data is stored in a numpy array called frame. By default opencv grabs a 640 x 480 image ( thats 640 on the x-axis and 480 on the y ). The numpy array has three dimensions, (x)(y)(BGR), so the first two dimensions have just one number in each specifying the x or y co-ordinate of the pixel. The third dimension contains three numbers, the RGB content of that pixel. Although for some reason the values are arranged BGR.

Therefore, changing the line

```
num = (frame[...,...,2] > 236)
```

to

```
num = (frame[...,...,1] > 236)
```

should do the trick for you.

To explain very briefly what this line does, it checks in a colour plane for high intensity values (over 236 - where min=0 and max=255) and keeps a note of all such pixels. The idea is that if you shine a red laser, the red colour plane will have a concentration of high intensity values around the dot area.